# Transposing Rows into Multiple columns SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a table with multiple rows that needs transposed to one row with multiple columns. The order in which the items are listed on my current table matters for ranking purposes, so I need them to stay in order when they are transposed into columns

[image: Click here to see my current table and desired table]

Thanks in advance

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, sorry, sql server

Comment: How many HL do you need? is 4 predefined?

Comment: Some will have 1, some will have 2, some will have 3. There are different possibilities for total number of Item_numbers and HL2 Codes for each individual_id

Comment: Is there a column you can use to specify the order of the rows for purposes of this pivot?

Comment: @TabAlleman I can add one. Lets just say there is a column called "Rank" next to the Item number column that would rank each item

Comment: Can you post ddl (create table) and sample data (insert statements) so can help? My guess is you need a dynamic crosstab or pivot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` & do conditional aggregation :

```
SELECT individuaid, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN seq = 1 THEN item_no END) item_no_1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seq = 1 THEN HL2_CODE END) HL_2_1,
       . . . . 
FROM (SELECT t.*,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY individuaid ORDER BY item_no) AS seq
      FROM table t
     ) T
GROUP BY individuaid;
```

Comment: Do you mean conditional aggregation? :)

Comment: ordering by item_no would not give the desired results shown in the question.